# Novice javac import library (httpclient) command line

Tags: java, apache

I have this .java and cannot compile it successfully. I downloaded the httpclient apache from the apache website and tried to compile it with the following command.

javac -cp /httpcomponents-client-4.3.4/lib/*.jar;. PostToServer.java

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

public class PostToServer {


public final static String postapiURL = "http://www.google.com";

public PostToServer() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    postAPI(postapiURL);

}

public static void postAPI(String urlString) {

    try {

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Here's the files under the directory

```
~/CallServer$ ls -l httpcomponents-client-4.3.4/lib/
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar
httpclient-4.3.4.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.4.jar
```

Compilation Error:

```
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
The program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
bash: httpcomponents-client-4.3.4/: Is a directory
public: command not found
bash: //public: No such file or directory
public: command not found
bash: PostToServer.java: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: PostToServer.java: line 35: ` public PostToServer() {'
```

Answer (Thank you for the answer):
so after you downloaded the .jar binary files from the website, you basically have to rename those jar files and move them to org/apache/http/client/, where you have to create these folders manually.

Comment: I can't compile it. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Maybe. Please show us the compilation error. It will contain hints.

Comment: You seem to be trying to run the `.java` source file as a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is a bit off. bash treats `;` as a command separator, so everything after the `;` in the `cp` is a command (the separator ";" is for Windows). Then your library is in a subfolder not the root - so this,

```
javac -cp /httpcomponents-client-4.3.4/lib/*.jar;. PostToServer.java
```

Should be,

```
javac -cp httpcomponents-client-4.3.4/lib/*.jar:. PostToServer.java
```

Comment: I have the following error. PostToServer.java:9: error: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

Comment: Sorry ... but which path?

Comment: Oh I figured it out. So basically I have to move the jar file to org/apache/http/client/, and I have to create all these folders manually. Sorry I'm still new to develop java program on command line. Thanks a lot!